# How can I use in 'opencv' function that get a color of pixel when I built a hide windows (run in background)?

Tags: c++, opencv

I build program that run in background and check if tow image are similar.
It's do good when I run it in standard running. But when I want run it in hide windows (in background) I get this errors:

1. > unresolved external symbol main ConsoleApplication2
2. > unresolved externals    ConsoleApplication2

Here my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <atlimage.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int APIENTRY WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR     lpCmdLine, int nShowCmd) {

  int count_inequality = 0;

  Mat image, image2;
  image = imread("hh.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR); // Read thVec3b intensity =   img.at<Vec3b>(y, x);
  image2 = imread("gg.jpg", IMREAD_COLOR); // Read thVec3b intensity = img.at<Vec3b>(y, x);
  float blue;
  float green;
  float red;
  float blue2;
  float green2;
  float red2;

  for (int i = 1; i <= 1000; i+=10) {
      for (int h = 1; h <= 900; h += 10) {
        Vec3b intensity = image.at<Vec3b>(i, h);
        blue = intensity.val[0];
        green = intensity.val[1];
        red = intensity.val[2];

        Vec3b intensity2 = image2.at<Vec3b>(i, h);
        blue2 = intensity2.val[0];
        green2 = intensity2.val[1];
        red2 = intensity2.val[2];

        if (blue == blue2 && green == green2 && red == red2) {}

        else {
              count_inequality++;

              if (count_inequality == 3){
                  //Code what happens if will be 3 inequality.
              }
          }

        }
    }
return 0;
}
```

**Can someone help me?**

Comment: Where do those happen? I'd guess that you use some function in one of your includes improperly and the error happens there. Btw, try to avoid "using namespace std;", std is quite big and hard to keep an eye on. Better do that with single parts of std, like "using std::cout;"

Comment: You don't understood my problem. my problem is because that I use in external library that her function of 'get color pixel' are not matching to hide windows (run in background).

Comment: @Eliyahu-Shmuel well you really didn't explain your issue well. Anyways, if you set the subsystem to "Console" then the entry point is `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` not `WinMain`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of the project `ConsoleApplication2` so I'm going to assume that you used the Visual Studio project template for "Console Application".

That template sets [`\SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fcc1zstk.aspx) option which means that the program wants to start with a function that has the signature `int main(int argc, char* argv[])`

So you need to change that option to `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS` or you need to change the signature of your `WinMain` function.

Comment: so you're telling me that it still says that it can't find `main` the entry point when you set `/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS`? Can you please be more specifc, what did you try and did anything change (different error, etc)?

Comment: it's give me same errors and I gone to the project properties for Linker | System | SubSystem and set it to Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS)

Comment: @Eliyahu-Shmuel did you set it to the right subsystem in the same configuration (Debug/Release) and platform (Win32/x64) that you are compiling? Does the complete error log say where the reference is used (most of the time there's a "referenced in xyz" string after the "unresolved reference")?